# HTTPCookieStorage not persisting a cookie

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I couldn't find anything in the docs but did read on a forum that `HTTPCookieStorage` does not persist a cookie whose `expirationDate` is null. Is this indeed the case? And if so, what's the best way to make it so it does persist it (forever)?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would set a ridiculously far-future date, e.g. twenty years from the date that you set the cookie.  And, of course, whenever you connect to the server again, you would also typically bump that expiration date to twenty years from that point.

Or if you're doing this in code (rather than on the server), you can probably use `[NDSDate distantFuture]`.